# Let $A_1 \subset X_1$ and $A_2 \subset X_2$. Show that $\operatorname{int}(A_1 \times A_2) = \operatorname{int} (A_1) \times \operatorname{int} (A_2)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $A_1 \subset X_1$ and $A_2 \subset X_2$. Show that $$\operatorname{int}(A_1 \times A_2) = \operatorname{int} (A_1) \times \operatorname{int} (A_2).$$

$”\subset”$ Let $x =(x_1,x_2) \in \operatorname{int} (A_1 \times A_2)$. This implies that $\exists O_x \subset \operatorname{int} (A_1 \times A_2)$ that’s open. Now $O_x  = \Pi_{i=1}^2 O_{x_i}$ and so $x_1 \in O_{x_1}$ and $x_2 \in O_{x_2}$. This in turn implies that $x=(x_1,x_2) \in O_{x_1} \times O_{x_2} \subset \operatorname{int} (A_1) \times \operatorname{int}(A_2)$

$”\supset”$ Let $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \operatorname{int} (A_1) \times \operatorname{int}(A_2)$. This implies that $\exists O_{x_1}, O_{x_2} \subset \operatorname{int} (A_1), \operatorname{int} (A_2)$ respectively. Now $x_1 \in O_{x_1}  \subset \operatorname{int} (A_1) $ and $x_2 \in O_{x_2} \subset \operatorname{int}(A_2)$ and now since $O_x =O_{x_1} \times O_{x_2} \subset \operatorname{int} (A_1 \times A_2) $ we have that $x \in \operatorname{int} (A_1 \times A_2) $.

Is this a valid solution for the problem? I cannot immediately see why this wouldn’t work?

Comment: It's a priori not true that $O_x=O_{x_1}\times O_{x_2}$... take for example $O_x=\{y\mid |x-y|<1\}$ (where $|\cdot |$ is the euclidian metric in $\mathbb R^2$). Then, you cannot write $O_x$ as a product of two open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Not even in the product topology?

Comment: No, the set $O_x$ I gave you below is open in the product topology.

Answer (score 2):

In $\subseteq$, it isn't true that all open subsets of $X_1\times X_2$ may be written as the product of two open sets. A generic open subset of $X_1\times X_2$ is the union of a family of such subsets; therefore, either you refer to $O_x$ being from the obvious base of the product topology, or you refer to it being an appropriately chosen neighbourhood (which is more or less the same).

In $\supseteq$, I don't necessarily see a mistake, but the point is that $\operatorname{int}(A_1)\times \operatorname{int}(A_2)$ is open and it's a subset of $A_1\times A_2$, therefore it's a subset of $\operatorname{int}(A_1\times A_2)$ by definition. I see a mention of many details, but not of the important containement in $A_1\times A_2$.